# Cannot access current user id using flask_login in MethodView

Tags: flask, flask-login

I have a problem accessing user-id inside a POST request in Class-based views. Inside a GET method, I can easily get data. I guess the problem is because my POST method is not decorated with `@login_required`, but I cannot decorate POST since getting an error, what is a workaround to access logged user id?

Authenticate.py

```
class Authenticate(MethodView):

  def post(self):
    ...some code
    login_user(user, remember=True)
    g.user = current_user.id
```

In this class, I want to access users id

```
class User(MethodView):

  def post(view):
    # not working
    print(current_user.id)
    print(g.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Flask-Login, you should have `user_loader` callback function

```
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)

@app.login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(_id):
    user = users[_id]
    return user
```

This assumes that your `login` or `authenticate` endpoint saved the user somewhere before `login_user`. For simplicity the above snippet stores it in python dictionary where key is your unique user_id and the value is your user's information.

Now when any of your endpoints are called, this user_loader callback function is called and the current_user object is populated with your the returned user (`return user`)

For your code it might work like that

```
  def post(self):
    ...some code
    ## New code ##
    save_user(user._id, user)
    login_user(user, remember=True)
    return {"state":"authenticated"}, 200
```

Of course save_user() should save the user somewhere accessible by the user_loader callback